# Jenkins - Run exe and check output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins, so my question is really simple. 
I would like to run an exe and check if the output text file is as expected.
So:

1. Grab the artifact the SVN  (OK!)
2. Run and exe  with some command line arguments (OK!)
3. Check the output text file (Don't know how to do it)

Any help?

Bonnus: Instead of running an .EXE located in SVN, is there a way to build the C# .NET code to generate the release .EXE ?

Comment: add a build step "run Windows batch command" and run your exe .. or add a batch script that does it and check the return values. Is it that what you want?

Comment: @TWE, yes, that's what I want. The only problem is that I don't know how to check if the content of an output file is as expected.

Comment: Unless your output is some kind of standard for build environments (like junit xml files or something like that) there is no way that jenkins will parse it for you. You will need to write an own parsing tool or script that will check it. Probably as a separate build step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the contents of the output file using any scripts. I used NAnt's loadfile to load the whole file. I am sure that there will be an ANT version of loadfile task too.

http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/tasks/loadfile.html

Regarding the second question, you can use the MSBuild plugin to compile your code and generate the Release exe. There are parameters which you can pass to MSBuild to do it.